Parse a comma separated list of values enclosed in <>, each element may contain (<>,)
I have a variable-length list of values that are formatted as follows:
[<value1>, <value2>, <value3>, ...].

However, each value can contain the characters <>,. So an example of how the list might actually look is
[<<a,b>>, <c: d/<e>>]

From this example, I want to extract the values <a,b> and c: d/<e>.
Thanks in advance for anybody who can help!

First off, this isn't really a job for regexes. Second, are the elements guaranteed to have balanced angle brackets?

In general, you need a parser here, not regex.

What language/regex flavor are your using? It is possible if you're using PCRE: <((?:[^<>]|(?R))*)>

What language are you using? This seems more like a job for a split-and-trim operation. For example, in JS str.slice(1, -1).split(/, (?=<)/).map((s) => s.slice(1, -1))

Assuming a maximum nesting depth of 1, group 1 of each match of:
<((?:[^<>]+|<[^<>]+>)*)>

See live demo.
